# What is asbestos cement sheet?

Tags: safety, asbestos

How do I tell if I have asbestos **cement sheet**?

How should I remove an asbestos cement sheet?

Comment: See: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/166/asbestos-removal - not a duplicate at all, but related. I also suggest ignoring the suggestion to DIY because I don't believe it's safe and the person who answered is putting people at risk.

Answer (score 4):

Call a professional.

I'm not sure there are really any diy ways to handle asbestos.  In most places you need a license, and lots of expensive equipment to remove asbestos.  You might be able to find somebody in your area willing to come out and take a look for free, if you are really lucky and they are really nice (or really hard up for work) they might even test it for free.  The removal will most likely be a bit costly though.

Comment: asbestos cement is not as bad as normal asbestos as you don't get any dust if you don't cut it etc

Comment: @Ian: but if you break it or crack it during removal, there could be dust.

Comment: @Ian: Tester101 is right. You really don't want to take any chances with that stuff.